# regular normal distribution on the subset $\left \{ a\cdot t\mid t\in\mathbb{R} \right \}$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Assume $Y$ is standard normal distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ and we construct a new random variable with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such

$X=aY$

It is obvious that $X$ is not a regular normal distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$ but on that subset $\left \{ a\cdot t\mid t\in\mathbb{R} \right \}$. My question is that how can I decide the parameters of this regular normal distribution on $\left \{ a\cdot t\mid t\in\mathbb{R} \right \}$?

Comment: See the degenerate case of multivariate normal on Wikipedia.

Comment: @user251257 my wrong, it was meant as a subspace, not an affine subspace

Comment: it is basically the same. Just try to adapt the result from Wikipedia.

Comment: Found it. Thanks

Comment: The support of both $X$ and $Y$ is the real line. If $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ then $Y = aX \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0, \sigma = |a|),$ for $a \ne 0.$  [If $a=0$ then $Y$ is degenerate, placing probability $1$ at $0.$] // What role does $b$ play in this question? Did you intend $Y = aX + b?$